# How to show one bar plot per year in figure

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

Good day,

I have a simple question, for which I can't seem to get a solution. I have a data frame with the number of students attending a specific class per year. I want to make a bar chart with the class id on the x-axis and the number of students on the y-axis, with a **range slider** showing only one year at a time.

Here is my data:

**in:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go


d = {'year': [2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022,], 
     'class_id': [101, 102, 103, 101, 102, 103, 102, 103, 105, 105, 106, 107, 106, 107, 108, 106, 107, 108], 
     'num_students': [24, 23, 11, 35, 22, 16, 36, 33, 33, 23, 37, 36, 37, 43, 37, 39, 29, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**out:**

```
    year    class_id    num_students
0   2017    101         24
1   2017    102         23
2   2017    103         11
3   2018    101         35
4   2018    102         22
5   2018    103         16
6   2019    102         36
7   2019    103         33
8   2019    105         33
9   2020    105         23
10  2020    106         37
11  2020    107         36
12  2021    106         37
13  2021    107         43
14  2021    108         37
15  2022    106         39
16  2022    107         29
17  2022    108         11
```

Here is the chart:

```
data = [go.Bar(
   x = df.class_id,
   y = df.num_students
)]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
```

[image: Barchart]

Now I need to add a slider that will only show one year's data at a time and not a stacked bar chart with all of the data, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: But with slider, you will find it difficult to hide other years when you play manually with the min and max, you will find yourself to add other years and the figure is messed up. I suggest to use buttons for years to show one graph per year.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

d = {'year': [2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022,], 
     'class_id': [101, 102, 103, 101, 102, 103, 102, 103, 105, 105, 106, 107, 106, 107, 108, 106, 107, 108], 
     'num_students': [24, 23, 11, 35, 22, 16, 36, 33, 33, 23, 37, 36, 37, 43, 37, 39, 29, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['class_id'] = df['class_id'].astype(str)
```

Here is the plotting part:

```
fig = go.Figure()

for y in df.year.unique():
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.query('year==@y')['class_id'],
                        y=df.query('year==@y')['num_students'], name=str(y)))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "type": "buttons",
            "showactive":True,
            "active":0,
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": str(y1),
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"visible": [y1 == y2 for y2 in df.year.unique()]}
                    ],
                }
                for y1 in df.year.unique()
            ]
        }
    ]
)

fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace: trace.update(visible=False) if trace.name != str(df.year.unique()[0]) else ()
)

  
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hamzah! That looks great. I didn't know that buttons were possible. I'm only starting out with Plotly so I still need to learn a lot. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, If you find this solution answer your question, please accept the answer and vote up :)

Comment: will do. I will still try to see if I can get a slider to work. Thanks!